# android : SQL Exception while querying

Tags: android

Team,

Can you please help me to understand why I m getting the following exception.

05-07 10:57:20.652: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(470): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "1": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT Id,Name FROM act WHERE Id 1-IJUS-1

Thanks in advance,

Comment: can you please copy and paste the code you are using, i didnt get any information from the error statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL is invalid. You may be missing an equals sign and some quotation marks around the value:

```
SELECT Id,Name FROM act WHERE Id="1-IJUS-1"
```

However, without knowing your table structure, it is difficult to know for certain. The [SQLite documenation is freely available online](http://sqlite.org/lang.html) for more on [how to construct a SQL query](http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html).